# Iterables/generators explanation

Tags: python, generator, iterable

Can somebody explain how the `__next__` works with the code below?  I know 'next' is used for iterators to grab the next item of an iterable, usualy with `next()`.

I know the `__iter__` part gets executed because of `list()` call which executes `__next__`.  But `__next__`keeps executing, almost like a while loop? Until StopIteration is executed?

Also, where are all the 'return' elements getting stored under `__next__`?  Is it all just stored in memory until `return self` under `__iter__` returns it to the calling function?

```
class FRange(object):
    def __init__(self, start, stop=None, step=None):   
        if stop is None:
            self.i = 0
            self.stop = start
            self.step = 1
        elif step is None:
            self.i = start
            self.stop = stop
            self.step = 1
        else:
            self.i = start
            self.stop = stop
            self.step = step

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):                             
        if self.i < self.stop and self.step > 0:
            self.i += self.step
            return self.i - self.step
        elif self.i > self.stop and self.step < 0:
            self.i += self.step
            return self.i - self.step
        else:
            raise StopIteration


def rangeFloat(args):
    return list(FRange(*args))
```

The code above produces for example:

```
For args = [-1.1, 2.4, 0.3], the output is
rangeFloat(args) = [-1.1, -0.8, -0.5, -0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 1, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 2.2].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list` basically works like

```
def list(thing):
    result = []
    for item in thing:
        result.append(item)
    return result
```

and a `for` loop:

```
for item in thing:
    # loop body
```

works like

```
iterator = iter(thing):
while True:
    try:
        item = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    # loop body
```

Putting these things together, `list` calls your `FRange` instance's `__iter__` method to get an iterator; in this case, the iterator is your `FRange` instance itself. It then calls `__next__` repeatedly and appends all `__next__` return values to the list until `__next__` raises `StopIteration`. Once `StopIteration` is raised, `list` returns the list it built.

Comment: should next(iter) be next(iterator)?

Comment: @user1179317: Indeed it should.